# how to make UItableview to be with format length

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I am doing a homework where i have to receive the incoming message from the NSInputstream  and have to view it in UItableview, i can receive the message and send the message properly , but some time my string is writing in the same line even though i give in \n.

do any one have idea ????

for example:
 @abc:123:123:123:123@
 @abc:123:123:123:123@
 @abc:1:2:3@

first line prints in the first row but in second row prints third line also , can any one tell me how to make a format where if string starts and ends with "@" will write in each row not in the same row.

i made lots of filter message but it fails

my code:

```
    case NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable:

        if (theStream == inputStream) {

            uint8_t buffer[1024];
            int len;

            while ([inputStream hasBytesAvailable]) {
                len = [inputStream read:buffer maxLength:sizeof(buffer)];
                if (len > 0) {

                    NSString *output = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:buffer length:len encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

                    if (nil != output) {
                        NSLog(@"server said: %@", output);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        break;
NSIndexPath *topIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:messages.count-1 inSection:0];
[self.tView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:topIndexPath 
                  atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle 
                          animated:YES];
```

---

output:
 @abc:123:123:123:123@
 @abc:123:123:123:123@  @abc:1:2:3@

But wat i am expecting :

@abc:123:123:123:123@
 @abc:123:123:123:123@
 @abc:1:2:3@

.... if the string starts and ends with "@" has to write in the next line... the problem is because the some time string is small so it takes the same line , but i want it in the next line if starts and ends with "@"

Comment: can you include the expected output and what you get now?

Comment: i updates my question  as per your question .. do you have any idea ?? i did everything this is the last thing which i have to finish

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of array by separated by components..

```
    NSString* string = @"@abc:123:123:123:123@@abc:123:123:123:123@123:123:123:1@abc:1:2:3@123:123:123:1@abc:123:123:123:123@@abc:123:123:123:123@ 123:123:123:1@abc:1:2:3@ @abc:123:123:123:123@@abc:123:123:123:123@123:123:123:1@abc:1:2:3@ 123:123:123:1@abc:123:123:123:123@123:123:123:1@abc:123:123:123:123@123:123:123:1@abc:1:2:3@";

NSMutableString* formatString = [NSMutableString string];

NSArray* strArr = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@"@"];
for (NSString* str in strArr)
{
    [formatString appendFormat:@"%@@\n@",str];
}
NSLog(@"%@",formatString);
```